Tomcat V9 in Docker: localhost:8080/manager/html is not accessible
I would like to deploy my Java Servlet Application (University Project) as Docker Container in Compose environment. But I get an 404 on the root route. Even the route "localhost:8080/manager/html/" is not accessible.Have I missed something in my Dockerfile?
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 as build

WORKDIR /deploy
COPY . .
RUN mvn compile war:war -DskipTests

FROM tomcat:9-jdk17-temurin
COPY --from=build /deploy/target/amazonlite-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]


TDLR: You need to share the port when you run the image using -p 8080:8080. And the URL is probably something like
http://localhost:8080/amazonlite-1.0-SNAPSHOT.
Details
Suppose that your project looks like this:
├── Dockerfile
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml

 Dockerfile precisely as included in the original question.
 index.jsp a simple component just to "do something!".
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Hello from AmazonLite!</h2>
</body>
</html>

To build and run:
docker build -t amazonlite .
#  The important bit here is the -p argument.
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 amazonlite

The -p 8080:8080 option will ensure that port 8080 on the container is available as port 8080 on the host.
If you go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ you'll get a 404 error. You need to go to http://localhost:8080/amazonlite-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ to see the test page. You'll need to customise the path as required, but this will at least get you connected to your service!

